# Laravel view @include auto logout when refresh

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.5 with mysql database, session storing in database.

**@Problem :**  Whenever I refresh or go into another page, it will log me out and redirect me back to the login page.

**@Cause :** After debugging, I found out whenever I @include a view `top.blade.php` inside my view template named `master.blade.php`, when I refresh the page, it will auto log me out and killing off the session.

The codes inside `top.blade.php` :

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">

  <!-- Mobile Menu -->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Header Icon -->
    <a  href="{{ url('/') }}">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="{{ asset('images/head.png') }}" alt="Little Project">
    </a>

    <!-- Message Of The Day -->
    <div class="navbar-text visible-xs"><p>Little Project</p></div>
    {{ Auth::user()}} <!-- to check the user info if it retains -->
</div>



<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

<!--Right side of the NavBar -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      @guest
        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
      @else
        <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Demo</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Logout</a></li>
      @endguest
  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

While the `master.blade.php` file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>

<!--meta header-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Little Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('constants.top')
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Contents -->
      @yield('content')

    </div>


    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Upon login, successful display of information at both top.blade.php and master.blade.php to check the User's login information]

However when refresh, it will destroy all sessions as long as I @include `top.blade.php`

Comment: Appreciate for your feedback, I have found my problem which is actually calling out the `Auth::logout()` everytime I load the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem,

The fact that I have `<li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Logout</a></li>` within my `top.blade.php` file, it will auto call out the logout everytime it loads the page. **Bad practice !!**

What should be done is to have a post method directed to the `logout controller` through form with `csrf_field()`

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you are using the `web` middleware group for your route.and ensure the `web` middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php` has the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` included